# How to decode raw binary to hex

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, decode, codec

I'm required to decode a raw binary value that looks like `b'\xa3\x13\xa4;\xcb\xda\x1b\x1b,Ut\xde\xeb2\xb5\x84\xe5&\x85;'` to a hex value which then would look like `0x90D152B5ED57E00336FD8E106A7BCE28FC3EA588`.

I've tried to use raw_bin.decode("hex"), but that tells me to use `codecs.decode()`, but I'm lost..

How can I decode `b'\xa3\x13\xa4;\xcb\xda\x1b\x1b,Ut\xde\xeb2\xb5\x84\xe5&\x85;'` to `0x90D152B5ED57E00336FD8E106A7BCE28FC3EA588` in python?

Comment: `import binascii; binascii.hexlify(b'\xa3\x13\xa4;\xcb\xda\x1b\x1b,Ut\xde\xeb2\xb5\x84\xe5&\x85;').decode()` will give you `'a313a43bcbda1b1b2c5574deeb32b584e526853b'`

Comment: thank you! that's already better, but it's not quite there yet. I get `b'4e79c534c4fe926f9a0c7c7d3a7112252bfa5b4d'` (this might not be the same value) but I'd need `0x4e79c534c4fe926f9a0c7c7d3a7112252bfa5b4d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`binascii.hexlify`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify)

```
>>> x = b'\xa3\x13\xa4;\xcb\xda\x1b\x1b,Ut\xde\xeb2\xb5\x84\xe5&\x85;'
>>> binascii.hexlify(x).decode()
'a313a43bcbda1b1b2c5574deeb32b584e526853b'
```

Convert it to number using [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) with `base` parameter as 16:

```
>>> int(binascii.hexlify(x), 16)
931003516565576134942949873523045876335469036859
>>> int(binascii.hexlify(x), 16) == 0xa313a43bcbda1b1b2c5574deeb32b584e526853b
True
```

Comment: thank you very much, this seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.. But when I use the `int(binascii.hexlify(x), 16)` to `SELECT` it states `The floating point value '950e5119' is out of the range of computer representation (8 bytes)`

Comment: @DaedalusMythos, I think you missed `base` argument 16.

Comment: @DaedalusMythos, BTW, what do you mean `SELECT` ?

Comment: I use the decoded value in a script and the value is later used to fetch additional data from a table.. how I currently use it.. `variable = int(binascii.hexlify(row['SHA1']), 16)`

Comment: @DaedalusMythos, I think it's problem with SQL, not the problem of `int(...)`. Try to print `variable`: `print(variable)`. It should work.

Comment: I see, thank you for the assistance! I'm now using `binascii.hexlify(x).decode()` and in the SQL statement use the value within single quotes and it seems to work.

Comment: I have to correct myself.. I'm using `binascii.hexlify(x).decode()`, without any quotes but a leading `0x` in the query.